# Linking to elements within different documents

Tags: javascript, html

I have used the 'prompt' method into asking for a character  name. however i am wandering if i can save that data to then use again in different html documents, to use the characters name in context. I am currently using Javascript and would like to try and use that to solve this issue.

Comment: An specific example with the problem is more preferable .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to access the data input by user on another page (must be same origin).

```
var value = prompt('Please enter your name');
if (value) {
  localStorage.setItem('username', value);
}
```

To get the saved data on another page, use:

```
localStorage.getItem('username');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign a variable prompt function. The user input will be saved in this variable.

```js
var saveMe = prompt('What time is it?')
console.log (saveMe)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store data and use them only locally you should maybe use the local storage, this allow you to save data into the user's browser. But you should know that old browsers do not support that.

Look at the W3School class about [local storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Here is an example of how it works :

```
localStorage.setItem("userName", prompt('Your name'));
```

And then when you need to access it :

```
localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```